# Significance of $R^2$

Tags: regression, excel

I have set up a linear regression array in Excel and now want to test the significance of my $R^2$ value at a certain level of significance. I've only been able to find tables that give the critical $R^2$ value, but I want to test it at 99.73% level of confidence and none of them contain that specific value. Is there a way to calculate the critical $R^2$ value by hand?

Comment: 99.73 % sounds very specific. Why did you decide on that particular confidence level?

Comment: @MånsT That's the probability of being within 3 sd's from the mean of a normal.

Comment: The p-value for the regression F is the same as the p-value for the R^2 in regression. Yes, the critical value can be calculated by hand from the connection between F and R^2.

Comment: yes it is very specific...it's a mandated level from our field. how do you calculate the critical value?

Answer (score -1):

R2 and significance levels measure different things.

R2 is a goodness of fit measure: i.e. how well does your model explain the target variable

Significance of a parameter is only to establish if it has a non-zero slope, or in simpler terms a "significant" relationship to the target.

Generally, an R2 of greater than 0.6 would point to a model with good predictive power.
P-values of less than 0.05 would be considered significant.

You would need to understand the limitations of these guidelines though as they are subject to satisfying the assumptions of a linear regression.

Comment: thank you! I'm trying to test the significance of r; to set a criteria for the r value of a linear regression created by calibrators of an instrument. I have a tablet with critical values of r but it doesn't have any significance other than 95% and 99%